# Connecting to remote mysql database with API

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I am designing a desktop application in C#, which needs to be connected to my online mysql database. I tried to give access in control panel a "%" which means from any IP, but it is not working. May be the hosting provider (bigrock) not allowing that.

Alternatively, I am trying to write some code in online on PHP which will get the "sql" as parameter and returns the output as JSON format using json_encode.

Is there any alternate methods which is better approach.

Comment: Embedding credentials in an application is a bad idea. Why not write a server, or interface with a webserver for any queries? Most importantly, why do you need your application to connect to your database?

Comment: the database has to be accessible from outside, which is almost never true in the defaults.

Comment: I agree with @Elzo Valugi I had the the same problem and i solved it by contacting my provider.

Comment: It worked fine after I took dedicated IP  with same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What error do you get when you try to connect? Timeout = firewalled; Permission denied = permissions not right etc.

One solution is to create a proxy with pre-coded queries (let's call then "stored procedures") - you can then say "Run query 5, parameters A, B and C". As this would be server-server (not public) you just need to add some basic authentication system (e.g. shared rotating key, checksum using parameters etc), but also ensure the queries are not dangerous if any parameters are thrown at it.

Disclaimer: It's a solution, but I'm not actually recommending that I'd do it unless you're very sure it's safe!

Comment: In which case your credentials are wrong and the server is not firewalled removely. This indicates you should have permissions to connect removely - check with your host.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Cpanel ? If yes, then try adding your host in remote MySQL. 
Here the link http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/enable-remote-mysql-connections-in-cpanel/ if you are unsure on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise that you do not create a wildcard user that can connect to the database from anywhere using embedded MySQL credentials in your application.  *This is a bad idea*.

It would be extremely easy to determine the credentials used by your application and then a malicious user could directly connect to your DB server and begin issuing queries to your database.

They will be able to issue `SELECT` statements for any information in your tables, even info they shouldn't see.  It then becomes much easier to exploit any known or unknown vulnerabilities in MySQL much easier since now they have console access and can send data directly to the server.  If the account has the `DELETE` privilege, they can erase all the data in your table(s).

Also, having a PHP script that issues queries provided by the application/end-user is not ideal because one can still freely issue queries.  While that option is better than giving blanket access to a remote user, it is still a bad idea.

The way to go would be to identify all of the information that the C# application needs to access, and how, and write a simple web service/API that will receive parameters and issue its own queries and return the results using XML, JSON, or even SOAP.  Try to abstract the database access as much as possible from the outside world for the best security.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

Create a user with the host of your public ip ([www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com)).

If that doesn't work, create a user with your host as your public ARPA/PTR record:

```
>nslookup
> set q=ptr
> 8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa    name = google-public-dns-a.google.com

8.in-addr.arpa  nameserver = ns1.Level3.net
8.in-addr.arpa  nameserver = ns2.Level3.net
```

The host would then be set to `google-public-dns-a.google.com`.

The second worked, and I am not sure why for me on a project I worked on in the past, where you would have thought the IP address to be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have root access or access to my.cfg. If you can edit it, make sure the line "skip-networking" is commented or removed and it contains line "bind-address = *". Restart mysql after editing config.

Comment: As drew010 mentioned it is not a good idea to allow a user to connect from anywhere. But you can't specify more than 1 "bind-address" in MySQL configuration(you actually can, but the last specified will be preferred). Therefore I would leave "bind-address = *", but set the permissions for the user to connect only from specified IP.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you shouldn't access the database directly over the (public) network.

One way is to write a php script on the database server and access it via HTTP/POST.

You should authenticate the client via username and a hashed password. The data you are sending should be encrypted (eg with the users clear text password). Don't send complete queries, only what you want to do and the parameters. As example, you want the orders for the customer, you can send a post request with the following parameters
user=abc,password=9151440965cf9c5e07f81eee6241c042a7b78e9bb2dd4f928a8f6da5e369cdffdd2b70c70663ee30d02115731d35f1ece5aad9b362aaa9850efa99e3d197212a,data=EncryptedData

You can notice, that the password is an SHA512 Hash.

The data can be json or anything else:
{
"Command": "GetOrder",
"Limit": "10"
}

In your php code you do the following steps:
1. Authenticate the user, if the password is not correct, respond with error code etc
2. Decrypt the data
3. Execute a query
4. Return the result as encrypted data

If you don't want to store the clear text password in your database, you could store in your database the hashed value and use a double hashed value for authentication and single hashed value for encryption.

If you wan't to execute the queries with parameters from the request you should use prepared statements to prevent sql injection.

More information about en/decrypting in php see: http://php.net/manual/de/ref.mcrypt.php

Answer (score 0):

Like some answers suggested, I think you are firewalled by bigrock.

Now if you want to use AJAX/PHP, you need three things:
- your C# class to send requests and receive the result
- your HTML/JS (or jQuery) file to receive the request and hand it over to your PHP. Then send you the result.
- your PHP file to query your DB.

The AJAX seems superfluous to me, you could just send your query passing it through POST or a GET parameter (i.e. `example.com/query.php?req='SELECT * FROM clients'`)

The code would be as follow:

C# using [this class](http://codesamplez.com/programming/http-request-c-sharp) made by Ali Ahsan Rana:

```
//create the constructor with post type and few data
MyWebRequest myRequest = new MyWebRequest("http://www.example.com/query.php","POST","req=");
//use System.Web.Script.Serialization and myRequest.GetResponse();
```

Some [tutorial](http://atsung.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/javascriptserializer-example/) on System.Web.Script.Serialization.

On the PHP side:

```
<?php

  $request=$_POST['req'];
  $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=mydb;host=example.com';
  $user = 'ajay';
  $password = '0000';

  try {
      $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }

  $response = $dbh->query($request);     

  while ($rep = $response->fetch())
  {
        $response_array[] = $rep;
  }

  $response->closeCursor();

  $return = json_encode($rep);
  return($return);

?>
```

That's a quick draft but should work AFAIK.